# How do I select a specific column based on a variable in a MS Access query?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, query-designer

I have a large table with the following fields:

```
Date
Product_ID
AmountEUR_Field1
AmountEUR_Field2
AmountEUR_Field3
AmountEUR_Field4
AmountEUR_Field5
```

where each **AmountEUR** field represents the sales amount for a product.
The reason for having 5 different AmountEUR fields is that they are based on different Currency Rates (in example BeginingOfMonthRate, AverageMonthRate, EndOfMonthRate etc.).

I now want to copy a specific **AmountEUR** field to another table, but the **AmountEUR** field to be copied varies over time (sometimes it is AmountEUR_Field2, other times it is AmountEUR_Field5).
Therefore I need to select a specific column based on a variable from another table. (that variable should then have value between 1 and 5).

I have been thinking about making a new field called **AmountEUR_ToBeUsed** that is updated with the correct AmountEUR_Field, but that brings me back to the same problem of selecting the specific column I want copied.

Can a solution be made within the Access query designer, or do I need some VBA code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make this with the Access Query designer.

Specifically you will need the function `IIF`.

For instance, if you want to specify that before a date you wish to use AmountEUR_Field1, and otherwise AmountEUR_Field5 you can say:

```
IIF(somedate<#1/1/2011#,AmountEUR_Field1,AmountEUR_Field5)
```

Note, depending on the settings of your PC, you may have to say:

```
IIF(somedate<#1/1/2011#;AmountEUR_Field1;AmountEUR_Field5)
```

Comment: MOLAP, considering there's 5 different options, I'd recommend you try Switch() to return the field you want: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php